# Inequality with differences of arithmetic means

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $B_{0}, B_{1}, ...$ be a sequence of balls and set $u_{B_{i}}=\mu(B_{i})^{-1}\int_{B_{i}}{u}$. Why does it hold that $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{|u_{B_{i}}-u_{B_{i+1}}|}\leq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\left(\mu(B_{i+1})^{-1}\int_{B_{i+1}}{|u-u_{B_{i}}|}\right)}?$$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two comments: What have you tried so far, and is there some relation between the sequence of balls?

Comment: I added something, but I dont know if that assumption is necessary... what I tried was to look at this inequality term by term which is $|u_{B_{1}}-u_{B_{0}}|\leq \mu(B_{1})^{-1}\int_{B_{1}}{|u-u_{B_{0}}|}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|u_{B_i}-u_{B_{i+1}}|=|\frac 1 {\mu (B_{i+1})} \int_{B_{i+1}} [u_{B_i}-u]d\mu| \leq \frac 1 {\mu (B_{i+1})} \int_{B_{i+1}} |u_{B_i}-u|d\mu$. Just sum this over $i$.